# How to draw plot consisting of discrete vertical lines?

Tags: plotting

From the minimum representative data shown in Test1.txt,

Test1.txt

```
   674.80752         0.00010
   361.50964         0.00000
   361.50964         0.36920
   361.50964         0.00000
   241.09541         0.00050
```

the command `ListLinePlot[
 Import["D:\\Test1.txt", "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> " "]]` gives the expected line plot, as shown below.

[image: Test1]

However, if more data are provided, as shown in Test2.txt,

Test2.txt

```
   674.80752         0.00000
   674.80752         0.00010
   674.80752         0.00000
   361.50964         0.00000
   361.50964         0.36920
   361.50964         0.00000
   241.09541         0.00050
```

the command `ListLinePlot[
 Import["D:\\Test2.txt", "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> " "]]` gives unexpected line plot, as shown below. Notice that the wrong peak Y value, as well as the unexpected slope at the beginning.

[image: Test2]

Could you help to comment the reason ?

Furthermore, could you help to comment how to get the desired plot with even more data (exemplified using Excel and shown below) ?

Test.txt that contains complete data

```
   674.80752         0.00000
   674.80752         0.00010
   674.80752         0.00000
   617.01865         0.00000
   617.01865         0.00000
   617.01865         0.00000
   580.55360         0.00000
   580.55360         0.00000
   580.55360         0.00000
   547.28765         0.00000
   547.28765         0.00030
   547.28765         0.00000
   515.88403         0.00000
   515.88403         0.00000
   515.88403         0.00000
   487.75449         0.00000
   487.75449         0.00010
   487.75449         0.00000
   373.13197         0.00000
   373.13197         0.00010
   373.13197         0.00000
   365.98853         0.00000
   365.98853         0.00030
   365.98853         0.00000
   361.50964         0.00000
   361.50964         0.36920
   361.50964         0.00000
   334.67337         0.00000
   334.67337         0.00000
   334.67337         0.00000
   322.59519         0.00000
   322.59519         0.01550
   322.59519         0.00000
   313.54589         0.00000
   313.54589         0.00000
   313.54589         0.00000
   304.60108         0.00000
   304.60108         0.00010
   304.60108         0.00000
   298.18095         0.00000
   298.18095         0.00940
   298.18095         0.00000
   294.63336         0.00000
   294.63336         0.00040
   294.63336         0.00000
   290.90295         0.00000
   290.90295         0.06280
   290.90295         0.00000
   284.38184         0.00000
   284.38184         0.00040
   284.38184         0.00000
   282.48471         0.00000
   282.48471         0.00000
   282.48471         0.00000
   273.14982         0.00000
   273.14982         0.00000
   273.14982         0.00000
   270.12281         0.00000
   270.12281         0.01200
   270.12281         0.00000
   267.65783         0.00000
   267.65783         0.00020
   267.65783         0.00000
   263.58638         0.00000
   263.58638         0.07210
   263.58638         0.00000
   256.73573         0.00000
   256.73573         0.00010
   256.73573         0.00000
   254.91065         0.00000
   254.91065         0.05660
   254.91065         0.00000
   250.50499         0.00000
   250.50499         0.00470
   250.50499         0.00000
   248.76213         0.00000
   248.76213         0.00010
   248.76213         0.00000
   244.91711         0.00000
   244.91711         0.00070
   244.91711         0.00000
   244.37682         0.00000
   244.37682         0.00220
   244.37682         0.00000
   242.24400         0.00000
   242.24400         0.00000
   242.24400         0.00000
   241.09541         0.00000
   241.09541         0.00050
   241.09541         0.00000
```

[image: Test]

Comment: Use `ListPlot` with option `Filling->Axis`?

Comment: @MelaGo Thank you for your helpful suggestion ! However, `ListPlot[Import["D:\\Test2.txt", "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> " "], 
 Filling -> Axis]` or `ListPlot[Import["D:\\Test.txt", "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> " "], 
 Filling -> Axis]` still does not show the correct peak Y values. Could you help to comment the possible cause ?

Comment: add the option `PlotRange->All`?

Comment: @kglr It works ! Many thanks for your helpful suggestions !